# Display StorageItem thumbnail in Converter

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, async-await, windows-phone-8.1

In Windows Phone 8.1 Runtime we can only get the thumbnails of StorageItem asynchronously by using GetThumnailAsync() method.

I am trying to display the list of files in a particular folder with the thumbnail being set for each item in the list in the Converter.

However the Converter has to run synchronously. So is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of running *async* code in *Converter*, let your binding work when the task (GetThumbnail) is completed. [Here is a nice post from Stephen Cleary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn605875.aspx) about *Patterns for Asynchronous MVVM - Applications: Data Binding*.

You will find there a class which I think you can use - `NotifyTaskCompletion`. In code define:

```
public NotifyTaskCompletion<BitmapImage> MyThumbnail { get; set; }
// run somewhere your async job:
MyThumbnail = NotifyTaskCompletion<BitmapImage>(file.GetThumnailAsync());
```

Then in xaml you can surely use a converter which will be run just after the task returns its result:

```
<Image Source="{Binding MyThumbnail.Result}" Visibility="{Binding
  MyThumbnail.IsSuccessfullyCompleted, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
```